# or conditions in where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Using the ActiveRecord where query finder, you can pass an array to return multiple records:

```
Model.pluck :id
 => [4, 6, 1, 5, 7, 3, 8, 9, 2, 10] 
Model.where(id: [4,6]).size
 => 2
```

I want to do the samething using mongoid where query finder, but it doesn't work:

```
ids = Contact.pluck :batch_record_id
=> [6]
size = Contact.where(batch_record_id: [6]).size
=> 0
```

How can I fetch the specified contacts, given an array of elements, as shown above?

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the [documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html) again, I noticed the in query finder:

```
Band.
  where(:founded.gte => "1980-1-1").
  in(name: [ "Tool", "Deftones" ]).
  union.
  in(name: [ "Melvins" ])
```

The in method allows you to specify an array of values.